# mysql_connect not updating the database after 60 secs

Tags: php

My mysql_connect database update does not update my database after 60 seconds, I have to refresh my website myself so the script will work. Does anybody know why? Is there some code that will prevent me from having it to refresh it myself? Here is my code:

```
  mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
  $res = mysql_db_query(db_name,"SELECT server_time_check FROM online_server"); 
  $serverTimech = mysql_result($res, 0, 0); 
  $serverTimecheck = time() - $serverTimech;  

  if($serverTimecheck > 60) { 
    session_start();
    mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
    $res = mysql_db_query(db_name,"UPDATE online_server SET server_time_check = '".time()."'");  
  }
```

Basically I have to refresh my websites page if not then script wont update my database. Does anybody know why? Is there a way to prevent this happening? Is there some code that will enable it?

Comment: Uhm, the code you've posted will only _select_ the server time. You don't really expect it to update anything, do you?

Comment: Is is the *database* or your *page* that isn't updating?

Comment: Are you expecting this to update your database automatically after 60 seconds (even after the script is done)?

Comment: yes automatically, am I missing mysql_close or something similar?

Comment: then you need to make the script run as service or using a cron job for every minute. The script is getting run again only when someone visits the script again. You could write a while(true) loop and use php sleep every 60 seconds. Ofcourse you could run the script from terminal too or by visiting the site but it won't be run automatically in these cases.

Comment: @JoniSalmi Yeah. But sleep will be a disaster for interactive web script. As the user will think. that the site has hanged.

Comment: You can't interact with php without ajax :) So maybe that's what you need

Comment: Once the page is loaded it won't change without refresh or javascript. And if you want data from server side, then you need to use ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry but with this coding, it will not do what you want it to do. Why? because this script is run only when the page loads and therefore it will only do the exact same thing every time. So how you can do this?
You need to use and external to this script via most likely javascript/ajax/jquery.
you can put a timer or counter that checks on the time difference and script runs the page for example:
i suggest you to use a session to hold the value when you make the connection to the database then after 60 seconds or any amount of time you run it, it can get the former value of the time of connection.

```
$.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                //data:$("#rfq_"+e).serialize(),
                url:"http://www.yoursite.com/yourpage.php",
                success: function(data){
                    //do your alert or actions upon succesful run of the url

                }, //end of success
                error: function(){

                    //do your code or action upon failre to run the script on the url
                    }// end of error


            });
```

i think this will do the trick for you.